# Polymorphic comments with nested resources in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, polymorphic-associations

I've followed the Go Rails tutorial below to set up comments with polymorphic associations: https://gorails.com/episodes/comments-with-polymorphic-associations

However, I have a nested situation with two models (movies/parts). It is working with 'movies' but I cannot get it working with child model 'parts'.

**Models**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end


class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Part < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :movie
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :movies do
  resources :comments, module: :movies
  resources :parts do
    resources :comments, module: :parts
  end
end
```

**app/views/movies/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: @movie} %>
<%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: {commentable: @movie} %>
```

**app/views/comments/_comments.html.erb**

```
<h1>Comments</h1>

<% commentable.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <div class="well">
  <%= comment.summary %> by <i><%= comment.user.email %></i><br><br>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**app/views/comments/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [commentable, Comment.new] do |form| %>
  <% if commentable.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(commentable.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% commentable.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.text_area :summary, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Add a comment" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Everything above with 'movies' is working well. The problem is with 'parts'.

**app/views/parts/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: @part} %>
<%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: {commentable: @part} %>
```

**Error with 'parts'**

NoMethodError in Parts#show
undefined method `part_comments_path' for #ActionView::Base:0x0000000003d3b0

**Highlighted line of error:**

```
<%= form_for [commentable, Comment.new] do |form| %>
```

---

I think I have to pass the movie object with the part object into 'commentable' -- since it is nested -- but don't know how to do it with this set up. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you run `rake routes` do you have a path named `part_comments`?

Comment: No, but I have `movie_part_comments_path`

Comment: ya that is what I thought, so the route in the partial is incorrect, it needs to also be nested under movies as well, right now it is looking for the route `/part/comments/`which does not exist, it needs to submit to `/movies/part/comments/`.  Fix that path in your partial and you should be fine.

Comment: Sorry, which path in which partial? The comments partials are working now with other (non-nested) models, so I'm not sure I can change the path there without breaking the path for those models.

Comment: The issue is you use the same partial for both of these I believe (`movie` and `part`), but the form needs to submit to different places so it gives an error in one spot.  you are correct changing it will create an error in the other spot, you need to either use two different partials or pass the URL to the partial as well.

Answer (score -1):

I believe route in the partial meant replacing any references to part_comments_path with movie_part_comments_path.